# TradingView Alerts at Wrong Exits

Tags: pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I've been having this problem where it would trigger entry at the right time but exiting is very weird. It would exit at random times.

My previous script I had "if (close[2] < open[2]) and (close[1] > open[1]) and (close[0] > open[0]) and (low[2] > low[1]) and (low[1] > low[0])" so I thought maybe it was looking for another pattern while in the trade and then setting up a new profit take. So I renew my script with "if (close[2] < open[2]) and (close[1] > open[1]) and (close[0] > open[0]) and (low[2] > low[1]) and (low[1] > low[0]) and strategy.opentrades == 0" but then it still exits way before the actual take profit. It alerted way before the take profit but when it the profit price is hit, it doesn't trigger, which is the first time this happened. I had to re-enter the trade and manually set up my Sell orders. The exit alerts have been working fine then this started happening for about a couple weeks now. Can anyone help me please?

Here's the snippet of my Exit code:

'''

```
fib_450 := lowest + (highest - lowest) * 4.50
plot(fib_450, title='Profit', color=color.new(color.green,0), style=plot.style_circles)
fib_stop := lowest - (highest - lowest) * 35.00
plot(fib_stop, title='Stop', color=color.new(color.red,0), style=plot.style_circles)
strategy.exit('Exit Long', from_entry='450', qty=1, limit=fib_450, stop=fib_stop, 
oca_name='OCA Name',alert_loss = 'Alert Stop', alert_profit = 'Alert Profit')

if str.contains(strategy.closedtrades.entry_id(0), "450")
    fib_450 := na
    fib_stop := na
```

'''